Meaning of の in this song
There is one part of this lyrics I couldn't understand:

いつか見てた波の 静けさの方へ海の底に消えた 優しさの方へ愛し合う未来を 確かに知っているの悲しみをこの手に 取り戻すその時まで二度とは来ない今 貴方のことしか見えない

I am not sure whether https://www.uta-net.com/song/49931/ after いつか見てた波 is subject-marking が or modifier for 静けさの方. This English translation seems to suggest that it is the former. It does not make sense to me because I know that が becomes の in relative clauses and I can't see which noun does いつか見てた波の静けさの方へ海の底に消えた優しさの方へ modify.

I think it's both in some sense.

波の静けさ

On surface, 波の modifies 静けさ ("quietness of the wave"). But semantically, there is a hidden subject-predicate relation between the two: 波が静かだ (minus the affirmation, I guess).
Similarly, the question

東京の暑さはどれくらいですか

presupposes that Tokyo is hot to some degree.
Translators can choose to translate semantically and not to mirror the syntactic structure, especially when dealing with creative language of lyrics.

Thanks. I wonder how do you understand the の方へ part in lyrics?

The verb is missing there, so what is meant is hard to grasp precisely. "Moving" towards might be a good guess, though.
